# Drawing line between two points?

Tags: android, line, android-canvas, geometry, android-drawable

I am developing game, in that game there will be grid of circles and player will connect those circles by connecting two circles with **line** vertically or horizontally, diagonal selection will not be allowed. 
What I have done so far is that **on canvas** I have drawn circles on board and I have displayed line when user swipes on screen. **I want to limit line's length according to internal distance of two circles and I also want to display horizontal and vertical line and it should not allow line other then these two.** lineDraw() method should take starting and ending parameters from drawCircles()'s x, y coordinates instead of taking input run-time from user. This is screen shot.

[image: Example]

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        int action=e.getAction();
        switch(action)
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downx=e.getX();
            downy=e.getY();
            Log.d("Umar", String.valueOf(downx));
            Log.d("Farooq", String.valueOf(downy));
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upx=e.getX();
            upy=e.getY();
            canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
            imageView.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```